# My IT career so far, need advice to move from Low Code profile to Full stack Developer

Tags: careers, career-switch

#VeryLongPost
#MyITCareerSoFar
#NeedAdvice

Hello everyone!!
I am kind of stressed about my career so far in IT and little worried to figure out how my future would be and wanted to share my IT career journey so far and ask advice from you on how and where I can proceed further in my IT career.

I was basically a Commerce student who didn’t find Commerce and business line interesting so decided to pursue my Masters in Computer Application which I was able to get admission since I was having Mathematics in my academics.

In between my Graduation and Master I took one year break since I didn’t get admission in a good college for pursuing MCA. I didn’t waste that year and just joined in a small company and was doing SEO(Search Engine Optimization) , Web Designing and Content writer job in that company.
There was IT department in the same company who was using Java, JSP, Servlets for web development back in 2008 and I found so much interesting to learn that and I used to observe and see what all work they are doing. I had enrolled for Computer course which I was doing side by side my Bachelors degree to get into IT. Whatever I learnt by observing things in this small company I used that knowledge to build my own Movie application using HTML CSS JSP and Servlets for back end displaying Movies and dynamic drop-down using AJAX in that application.

It gave me immense happiness and confidence that I can very well do good in IT industry. Once I completed my MCA in 2012, I could not clear campus interviews because my Quantitative aptitude was not good. I then started to work on improving my Aptitude skills and then in year 2014 there was a off campus recruitment drive conducted for a famous IT Services Company, I applied all that knowledge and cleared the aptitude as well as the Technical interview rounds for that company and got offer and started my IT career in year 2014. In between just to upgrade my Technical knowledge I joined as a Java trainer in a local institute where I taught Java, JSP and Servlets to college and school students.

It helped me improve my programming skills a lot and I got so much interest in learning Java. In year 2013 , Hibernate was trending web technology and I wanted to learn that but due to family priorities could not learn that.

Once I joined IT company in 2014 as a Fresher , I was given training in C++ , Java , Advanced Java ( JSP Servlets) and SQL.  I did well in the training and got to work with a very famous client in the same company. But when I got into that project , there was no Java work, it was all XSLT , C# and some XPP tool work . Since the project was very big it has front end team and shared services team. Front end team was working on ASP.Net and shared services on Java. The shared services team was divided into many small teams and the shared services module to which I belonged had the work of converting the HTML coming from front end to PDF and DOCS format which can be downloaded from the actual website.

I was interested in Java but still wanted to learn something so I tried to understand the full flow of the project and gave my best in my current team. There was migration to use ASPOSE API to convert the HTML documents to PDF and DOCS, I followed all design patterns and even though it was not web application development I was very much interested in that and gave my best in that.
But as I always wanted to work in Java, after 3 years working in same team , I asked my manager for a change so for 6 months I was put into a team in the same project where I would only run the selenium test cases and monitor and report any issues within the modules. I was not at all happy with this kind of work and talked to my manager for a change.

Then in 2018 starting I got into a team within the same project where the work was to resolve any issues within that module. Means it was basically support work but as well as new development work where we were migrating our current service to AWS. This module was basically Java Restful Web services written in Jersey involving concepts of multi threading , design patterns, database, Mockito test cases, Sonarqube fixes, Code coverage etc. Even though we did not write the code from scratch but resolving issues in the existing code itself made me learn so many things plus writing gradle scripts and cloud formation templates to upload these services to AWS cloud and using AWS S3 , EC2 , Lamda, Auto scaling and other services was very interesting to work upon. I really was enjoying my work here from 2018 till 2019 August

Then because of location change and other personal reasons I had to quit and I always wanted to get into a Product based company so I tried a lot to get into Product companies but I never cleared the Third round of interview. But luckily, I got hired in a Product company with good salary having only Four rounds of evaluation with first round online Aptitude and logical , one round about my previous experience and one round technical as a FULL STACK DEVELOPER. In the job description it was mentioned about RPA, AI and all so I thought it will be interesting to learn new things. I joined this company in 2020 Jan and in the beginning I went through lot of training for RPA(Blueprism) , React then BPM ( Workflow LOW CODE) etc.

These trainings were of no much use because the kind of work involved was all LOW CODE tools and there were already experienced people in that track who would take that work and complete it. The kind of work which I would be left to do it MANUAL TESTING of full flow because these are LOW CODE tools we cannot write automated test cases also for this. I really did not like this work and my base skillset which was Java and AWS now got changed. I am still interested to get into proper APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT kind of work.
But as I have mentioned previously, I was doing mostly support work and did not create a proper web application using NEW TECHNOLOGIES from scratch I don’t know how to approach into a Product company again for work. I don’t know how and from where to start my career to get back into that application development kind of work. With my current work profile I am sure I will not get into any Product company since LOW code is not what they expect.
HOW SHOULD I CHANGE MY CURRENT PROFILE WORK i.e 2 Years work into a kind of profile suitable for Application developer ( Full stack developer) kind of profile?
My interest has always been to be a full stack developer. In between last year in 2020 September I got chance to work in React for just 1 month but I still learnt a lot. I have documented those learnings of mine and I am sure it will be useful for me in future also.
If I want to take up small use cases and start working on React and Java or Python based application where can I get those use cases?? How can I try to include Programming work itself in my profile for whatever low code work( i.e designing workflows and Decisions) I have been doing??
I am sorry for such a long post. I am not satisfied with my current work and I really want to become a proper Full stack developer either in Python/React or Java/React technology stack. Please advice.

Comment: Can you shorten your post to an actual problem you face and don't know how to handle?

Comment: I thought giving a history about my career will help okay will reduce

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to code, just be the full stack developer you want to be. Build something in your spare time and start looking for a decent job with a good company.

Whilst a product based company may seem exciting, there's lot's of enterprise work out there where you can flex your full stack muscles.

Having your own app which you can demonstrate to a potential employer will put you in front of a lot of your rivals. Consider contracting over permanent roles too. I spent over 10 years working as a contractor and learnt a lot from some really smart people.

I also got to see some spectacular failures, which was just as educational and makes for some good tales from from the trenches.

Comment: Okay thanks for ur advice. U mean I shud participate in Hackathons or create my own Applications as my interest and passion whil I am working in the same company side by side ??

Comment: @newbie_learner yes, go and do something that you enjoy, and in the meantime start looking for a job with a company that will help grow your career, from the sounds of it these people don't really care about you.

Answer (score 0):

Being a full stack developer isn't anything special.  It's just knowing three (or more) different technologies and knowing how to use them together.

I've known back end developers that never learned the web side of things.  It didn't hurt their careers; but, if they need, they can probably learn the web side of things.

If you think full stack is going to open opportunities for you, go there; but, full stack developers tend to work in smaller shops where every aspect of the solution falls onto fewer people who make all the decisions.

On the other side of things, larger shops tend to use architects to split the problem up into components that are then programmed by people who primarily focus on their component.

There are also solutions that fall somewhere between these two extremes, and also lots of software that doesn't even involve a web stack.

There's more than one path to success; but, thinking full stack is the top of the mountain is kind of a mistake.  When you get up there, you might notice that there are many different mountains within sight.

Pursue the paths that are interesting to you; but, keep in mind who uses these technologies, as certain technologies are closely tied to certain industries, and if you specialize in an area which isn't the area you want to work in, you might find you need to add a new, different specialty to get to the area you want to work in.